# How to get current BTC rate for BRL(real) using php cURL or javascript

Tags: api, exchange-rate

Is there anyway to get current rate of BRL = BTC.

I saw the [blockchiain ticker](https://blockchain.info/ticker). But the value for BRL currency is not updated 
As listed [here in preev](http://preev.com/btc/brl).
I want to get the

```
 current 1BTC= how much BRL
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean that it's not updated?

Comment: @NickODell as the bitcoin value keep fluctuating, accordingly the value of the BRL currency also changing so this  value is not shown as it changes.

Comment: There are actually a couple of Brazilian exchanges that publish rates, but what they're not doing is providing an API. That's going to make it more difficult to curl in.

Comment: Something you could do is use the btc-e api to get the bitcoin to dollars or euros price, and find a forex api that does dollars or euros to Real, and mash the whole thing together.

Comment: @DoctorEvil Bitcoin is overcharged in Brazil, so your procedure won't return the actual price there. Mercado Bitcoin now has an API, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

BitPay have a JSON API on https://bitpay.com/api/rates
You can get BRL value with this command and calculate, (this API update every 1 minute)

```
curl -ks https://bitpay.com/api/rates | python -m json.tool | grep -iA 1 'Brasilian Real' | grep -i 'rate' | cut -f2 -d ':' | tr -d ' '
```

---

You will need:
- CURL
- Python 2.7+
- grep + cut + tr

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to [print](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) the value of 1 BTC in BRL with PHP.

You could manipulate the string containing the value for 1 BTC in BRL further if you need.

```
<?php

$jsnsrc = "https://blockchain.info/ticker";
$json = file_get_contents($jsnsrc);
$json = json_decode($json);
$one_Btc_To_Brl = $json->BRL->last;

print "1 BTC = " . $one_Btc_to_Brl;
?>
```

Comment: why Thiago Pereira answer requires so many additional setup but yours just plain PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [currency converter](http://www.converterhub.com) site, they might have updated rates for BRL = BTC

Answer (score 0):

You could start by parsing the JSON here:

https://bitpay.com/bitcoin-exchange-rates

Answer (score 0):

wget --no-check-certificate https://www.mercadobitcoin.com.br/api/ticker/

returns data that can be parsed relatively easily.